# Wine install: File properties (Detail view) not available in Office 2007

Tags: wine

I've installed MS Office 2007 using Wine.  The programs run fine, but when I want to open a file from within MSO, I can't see the file properties (Detail View: creation date etc). The columns are all there but they are blank.

I've used the "Windows" setting to change to Icon View and back to Detail View, but no joy.  Am I missing a DLL?  I used instructions from:

http://nithinaneeshsct06bt.blogspot.com/2012/05/install-microsoft-office-2007-in-ubuntu.html

I'm running 12.04 with all the latest updates, on a desktop Core2 Duo with 8GB of RAM.

Update 18/7/2013: Tried again in Word, Excel and Access.  The file dialog looks the same under all of these so I'm chalking it up to a dll issue.  I have MSO installations running on both my desktop and a laptop and they have the same issue.